# bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nodejs

I am trying to install nodejs on wsl but I faced this issue
Commands I tried:

```
brew install node
brew link node
node -version
-bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: Is it WSL version 1 or 2?

Comment: @Emmanuel it is version 1

Comment: @Emmanuel I tried many solutions and I read many documentation but nothing works

Comment: Without telling us what you have tried to fix it, it is nearly impossible for us to come up with an answer without having you try stuff that you have already tried.  I would suggest that you edit your question and show us what you have tried instead.  I did find that people were having issues the same way and changing to WSL2 could fix the error.  See https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8151#issuecomment-1141427494